# How to set the input to take the first one or first two or first three characters in batch?

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to figure out how the `"%var:~,1%"` setion of the provided code work.

I thought `"%var:~,1%"` would accept the first character correct and ignore everything else after.  `"%var:~,2%"` would accept only the first two correct characters and so on.  In this example "Y" would suffice for "YES".  "NO" would suffice for "NOO" and "CLS" would suffice for "CLS"

What happens is only option three "CLS" is a valid option.  I can change YES and NOO to `"%var:~,3%"` so that they are valid options.  But how would have `if /I "%var:~,1%" EQU "YES" goto :yes` accept a one character input?

````
:start
set /p var=is this a yes or no question?
if /I "%var:~,1%" EQU "YES" goto :yes
if /I "%var:~,2%" EQU "NOO" goto :no
if /I "%var:~,3%" EQU "CLS" goto :cls
echo not a valid choice
goto :start

:yes
echo this is YES but you only have to type first letter correct
pause
goto :start

:no
echo this is NO but you have to type the first two letters correct
pause
goto :start

:cls
echo this will CLS but you have to type the first three letters correct
pause
cls
goto :start```
````

Comment: `if /I "%var:~,1%" EQU "YES" goto :yes` is testing if the single, first character of `var` is equal to `YES`, which it never can be (because it's only one character!). Using `if /I "%var:~,1%" EQU "Y" goto :yes` would check that `var` is `Y`, `YES` or `Yanything-that-starts-with-a-why`.

Comment: Specifically, I think your problem is with "_would accept the first character **correct**_" ... the `~,1` construct has no notion of "correct"... it just extracts the given number of characters.

Comment: Ah, so as the variable name is longer that the one character that is being input ```"%var:~,1%"```  will never work.   Got it.  Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: Well, the variable name does not matter; you are comparing strings with different lengths, which are of couse never going to be equal...

Comment: I am not sure how to mark TripleHound's comment as the answer or how to mark it as "useful" but that answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

@TripeHound already explained in a comment that you are testing a single character against a word. it should just be `if /i "%var:~0,1%"=="y"`.

a  much better method however is to use `choice`

```
@echo off
:start
choice /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel.
goto :%errorlevel%

:3
echo this will CLS but you have to type the first three letters correct
pause
cls
goto :start

:2
echo this is NO but you have to type the first two letters correct
goto :start

:1
echo this is YES but you only have to type first letter correct
goto :start
```

If you are determined to not use `choice` this will work similarly using `set /p` by using only the first character of the word the user inputs.

```
@echo off
:start
set /p var=is this a yes or no question?
if /i not "%var:~0,1%"=="y" if /i not "%var:~0,1%"=="n" if not "%var:~0,1%"=="c" echo Incorrect choice & goto :start
goto :%var:~0,1%

:c
:C
echo this will CLS but you have to type the first three letters correct
pause
cls
goto :start

:n
:N
echo this is NO but you have to type the first two letters correct
goto :start

:y
:Y
echo this is YES but you only have to type first letter correct
goto :start
```

Comment: For some reason I always steer clear of  ```choice``` .  In this instance, the order of YNC after /C dictates which errorlevel is used.  That's interesting.  It seems I have to run this as administrator though.  I do not with ```set /p```

Comment: choice does not require admin rights at all. What windows version do you run? anyway, I added another method still using `set /p`

Comment: It is windows 10 version 1709. I wrote a totally different bat and it doesn't seem to run unless as administrator. I tried it on a win10 1903 too. So odd. I do better understand choice now. Thank you.

Comment: I commented out the @echo off to see what the output is.  It's like it's stuck in a loop with "C:\Users\name\Desktop>choice /C YNC /M "Press Y for Yes, N for No or C for Cancel." continuously scrolling down the screen.  When ran as admin, it works as expected.

Comment: The choice batch was named choice.bat.  When names something else it worked without admin privileges.  Thank you for your input.

Comment: No. Never call a batch file the same as internal system commands.